# Can i make a qrcode from a python function with django

Tags: python, django, function, qr-code

im doing a school project where i need a slackbot to send a message to the chat when scanning a qrcode. Im having problems finding a solution where i can convert the python function to a qrcode inside a html template.

**views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets
import os
import slack
import qrcode
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from django.contrib import messages


load_dotenv()
client = slack.WebClient(token=os.getenv("SLACK_TOKEN"))

#Index view
def home(request):
return render(request, 'rest/index.html')

#Beer function
def nobeer(request):
data = client.chat_postMessage(
    channel='#general',
    text="some text here"
)
qr.add_data(data)
qr.make(fit=True)
img = qr.make_image(fill='black', back_color='white')

messages.success(request, 'message sent to slack')
return render(request, 'rest/index.html')
```

**index.html**

```
<title>Slackbot</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='row'>
    <div class='col'>
      <div>
        {% load qr_tags %}
        {% qr_from_object nobeer “size” %}

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='col'></div>
        <form method="POST" action="/api/beer/">
           {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">send message</button>
      </form>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div>
      {% if messages %}
      {% for message in messages %}
       {% if message.tags %}  <script>alert("{{ message }}")</script> {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is significantly easier to generate the QR code on the client side using javascript, rather than trying to generate it on the server side. My advice would be to use a library like [qrcode.js](https://davidshimjs.github.io/qrcodejs/).

Answer (score 0):

i can see you are trying to use django-qr-code reusable app but you are importing pure python qrcode library

Try this (using python's qrcode library):

**views.py**

```
from io import BytesIO
import base64

def nobeer(request):

    data = client.chat_postMessage(
    channel='#general',
    text="some text here"
    )
    qr.add_data(data)
    qr.make(fit=True)
    img = qr.make_image(fill='black', back_color='white')

    buffer = BytesIO()
    img.save(buffer, format="PNG")
    img_str = base64.b64encode(buffer.getvalue()).decode("utf-8")
    messages.success(request, 'message sent to slack')
    return render(request, rest/index.html', {'my_qr_code': img_str })
```

**index.html**

```
<title>Slackbot</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='row'>
   <div class='col'>
     <div>
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ my_qr_code|safe }}">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col'></div>
    <form method="POST" action="/api/beer/">
       {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">send message</button>
  </form>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div>
  {% if messages %}
  {% for message in messages %}
   {% if message.tags %}  <script>alert("{{ message }}")</script> {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey @Tony, thanks for the help! Im getting an "undefined variable" error message on the img.save(buffer, format="PNG")

Comment: did you deleted your whole function and replaced it with mine ?

Comment: Yes, i left the client.chat variables there and added your solution to it

Comment: i have left a comment #same as above  in the code, you put  my part after the line   img = qr.make_image(fill='black', back_color='white')  in your function

Comment: @Roni do you want me to write another FULL answer ?

Comment: sure, if you have time for it! Would be nice

Comment: @Roni edited it, copy and paste the function and don't forget the import statements